# Connect oracle 10g from php 7.4 in wamp

Tags: php, windows, oracle10g, wamp

I'm using WAMP server, trying to connect to Oracle 10g database using php 7.4 in windows 11.

And the Oracle10g database is in another server.
So my codes is something like this:

$db="(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1xx.xx.xx.xx)(PORT = xxxx))(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = myserver)
)
)";

```
$c=oci_connect("username", "password", '$db');

if($c)
{
    echo "connection published..";
    
}
if(!$c)
{
    echo "Failed to connect.";
    
}
```

I've already enable **extension=oci8** in php.ini

But still got this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\wamp64\www\mysite\connect_ora.php

One more thing, after WAMP installation, there is no WAMP icon in the taskbar icon tray. I am not sure why. But the service is running as I can open the localhost, see the php info etc..

Comment: For WAMP, double-check that whether it is `extension=php_oci8.dll` . Make sure your restart the WAMP after the php.ini amendment.

Comment: Previously, the extension does not exists. So I've added the extension and restart WAMP, but it still showing the same error

Comment: Did you properly add/install the extension ? (1. change the php.ini and 2. install the oracle client and place the dll file in the extension directory and so on)

Comment: yes, and I also restart my laptop. But last time when I'm using php 5, in windows 10..i did not install oracle client, the connection works well.

Comment: You will need Oracle Client libraries, commonly but not always from Oracle Instant Client.  What Oracle software (which will have those libraries) is installed on the machine where PHP runs? I assume the DB is on some remote computer??